# Unity3D Input.GetAxis for Mouse not consistent

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am working on camera rotations based on mouseInput and i want it to have consistent sensitivity across all framerates. According to the unity documentation, the Input.GetAxis should be inherently framerate independent for the mouse movement.

What I am finding is that when i use the code below and change the framerate from 200+ to 30, the Input.GetAxis is returning very different outputs. For 200+ fps the GetAxis is low around like 2-5 where for 30 fps it is returning around 10-15 for the same mouse movements. Its causes a very drastic sensitivity difference in-game. Am i missing something? Thanks

```
    public Rigidbody _playerRigidBody;
private Vector2 _lookInput;
private void Start()
{
    //Application.targetFrameRate = 30;
}
private void Update()
{
    _lookInput.x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"); 

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    var sensitivity = 300f;
    var newPlayerRotation = _playerRigidBody.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(_lookInput.x * sensitivity * Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime);
    _playerRigidBody.MoveRotation(newPlayerRotation);

}
```

}

I have tested everything in this little function and the only thing that causes the issue is the Input.GetAxis. Its inconsistent. Any ideas or solutions or workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"framerate independent" means the value is depend on the movement of the mouse, it doesn't mean the value is consistent.

For framerate = 200, value = 2-5 means the mouse move 2-5 points in 1/200 seconds.

So to get the move distance during 1 second use:

```
_lookInput.x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") / Time.deltaTime;
```

Comment: Plus, you should add `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") / Time.deltaTime` to `_lookInput.x` in Update, and reset it to 0 on FixedUpdate, or there is no point of doing this.

Comment: Thanks Shingo, works great. Jichael, why do you say that? When i try that it doesn't become consistent. I don't have a firm grasp on frame rate independence clearly

Comment: You should never reference deltaTime in FixedUpdate, it is inconsistent. You should always use fixedDeltaTime if you're working in FixedUpdate. deltaTime is for Update.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer doesn't seem as simple as multiplying by Time.deltaTime. I did so yesterday, and it works better, but it is not a fix. According to Unity devs GetAxis("Mouse X") is inherently frame independent, thus adding a deltaTime multiplier will actually cause it to become frame dependent. I too am experiencing a large difference for 200fps versus 30fps, but deltaTime does not seem to remedy it. Perhaps it is something to do with mouse resolution... it really should just be 3 inches over time = 3 inches over time, but it's not behaving properly.